# It Is possibile to map typescript object to another based on interface/or type

Tags: typescript, types, interface, objectmapper, mapper

If i have an object in typescript

```
const x = {a:1, b:2}
```

And an interfacce

```
interface MyInterface { a: number }
```

It possibile to do something like (pseudocode) this

```
const y = Mapper<MyInterface>(x)

console.log(y)  // {a: 1}
```

And the result should be the object with the properties defined in the target interface

Something like mapstruct https://mapstruct.org/ in java